# External Storage for Xamarin on visual studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm currently working on Xamarin using Visual Studio to try and build and create an app that reads a bar code and saves the integer it gets from it in a .txt file. I have managed to make the code both read the bar code and save it however i was wondering if there is a way  i could save it in a more accessible file, as right now its saving in internal storage and the only way i can reach it is through adb console. 
Is there a way for me to perhaps save the integers on a .txt file on my laptop? I'm currently testing it on my physical phone and its connected to my laptop via a USB cable.

Here is my code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using Android.Content;
using ZXing.Mobile;
using System.IO;

namespace Scanner
{
    [Activity(Label = "Scanner", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button buttonScan = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonScan);
            TextView scanText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.scanText);
            var documents = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var BarcodesFile = Path.Combine(documents, "Barcodes.txt");
            buttonScan.Click += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
                var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
                var result = await scanner.Scan();

                if (result != null)
                    File.AppendAllText(BarcodesFile, "Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
                    scanText.Text = File.ReadAllText(BarcodesFile);
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is working with an external database or maybe a file on the internet perhaps an option? There are properly some api 's of sites where you can write in a txt file

Comment: That could work actually. I didn't know those existed but i will check it out now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So if api is an idea. I have not used any api yet for those requirements but when I think about txt I immediately thought about pastebin.

https://pastebin.com/api `enter code here`

That might be usefull to check out. Goodluck!;)

Comment: As much as i think pastebin is a good idea, i think i would prefer to simply save it on a file on my desktop. But i will try it.

Comment: Maybe look for an api like google drive, one drive. And than you can sync your computer with one of those drives ?

Comment: But is there no way i can access the internal files in my phone from my laptop?

Comment: You'll have to host a service on your computer than? Or try to sent it with Bluetooth perhaps. I'd just use a google drive api since that would be easyier to create and does the syncing for you.